# How can I fit a monte-carlo simulation into a 2D rectangular array

Tags: c#, simulation, montecarlo

I couldn't think of a more descriptive title so I'll explain my goal here.

I am building a monte-carlo simulation that runs 1000 runs of portfolio returns. My goal with this is to take the median time to reach the financial goal and some percentiles of that, and chart them.

The problem with this is that the simulations by definition will have different lengths, and when I go to chart them, some of the differing lengths will cut-off at different points, and makes finding median and percentiles almost impossible near the end.

Here is a picture demonstrating my problem (with 30 simulations).

[image]

I tried setting some conditions to make it more likely for the simulations to reach the same length (and not necessarily the same end goal) but some simulations (due to the random nature of monte-carlo simulations) last longer than expected.

Here is an image demonstrating that problem. Notice how the two bottom series last longer than the rest. I set the condition to continue either when the goal is reached or you've reached a limit of 60.

[image]

My ultimate goal becomes that I want the length of each simulation to match every other simulation, and that they reach the portfolio financial target, all while not being unnecessarily wasteful of resources (e.g. setting a length of 1000).

Here is the code of my monte-carlo simulation:

```cs
//Monte-Carlo
int simulations = 30;
double stockVolatility = 0.2;
double bondVolatility = 0.03;

List<decimal>[] stats = new List<decimal>[simulations];              

for (int i = 0; i < simulations; i++)
{
    List<decimal> po = new List<decimal>();
    po.Add(currentInvestments);
                    
    do
    {
        // Randomly generated return of the portfolio
        double pReturn = Investing.CalculateRandomPortfolioReturn(bReturns, bondVolatility, bondAllocation, sReturns, stockVolatility, stockAllocation);

        decimal x = po.Last();
        int k = 0;

        x *= (1 + (decimal)pReturn); 

        if (savingsGrowthRate > 0)
        {
            x += FinanceCalculations.FutureValue(initialSavings, k, savingsGrowthRate, 1);                            
            k++;
        }
        else
        {            
            x += initialSavings;
        }

        po.Add(x);
        stats[i].Add(x);
                        
        Thread.Sleep(5);
    } while ((po.Last() <= 1.05m * goal) /*|| po.Count < 60*/);
                     
    decimal[] temp = po.ToArray();
    GenerateChart(temp, "returns");
}
```

With this code, you might notice weird oddities here and there (like why `GenerateChart()` doesn't take the List and why I need an array), but most of it is because of other code in the application. I have a bit of commented out code at the `while` part of the loop that checks if the List has reached a length of 60. This is what causes the second graph. While commented out, it causes the 1st graph.

You might notice a variable `stats` being a List array. This array of lists is what I want to be a 2D rectangular array, that being an array with one set length and one set width. The width is this case would be represented by the count of the list, and the length by the amount of simulations. Normally, the array looks like this:

[image]

All sorts of different counts which cause the first graph. If I add the limit, it looks like this:

[image]

The underlines are cases where you have series that take longer than the limit to reach the portfolio financial goal.

As an aside, one glaring problem with my simulator is the `Thread.Sleep(5);`. I don't know why, but for some reason, not pausing the program causes this kind of error:

[image]

I have no clue why this is, and is probably way outside my expertise. My code runs perfectly fine with the sleep, but remove it and that is the result.

Anyway, that is a side-question (and I can make another question thread if requested), while my main request is to find a way to represent the portfolio returns in a 2D rectangular array.

Comment: There is no algorithm that will work for both cases you posted.  The issue is with the threshold : while ((po.Last() <= 1.05m * goal),  The 2nd chart the bottom two lines do not get to the threshold in the same number of samples as the other lines.  You could truncate using minimum to remove the extra points.  But then the 1st chart you would loose a lot of important information.  The problem with the 2nd chart you do not know what the minimum is going to be until you run all the simulations.

Comment: @jdweng This website seems to be able to do what I want (i.e. same length simualtions that reach the goal): https://engaging-data.com/fire-calculator/.

Comment: What criteria do you want to use to clip the data?  You could run an algorithm that says you want to plot 95% of the points.  You could say you want all the point less than 80.  But there is no one algorithm that will work in every case.  What one person says is needed other people will say is not needed.